# Radio type not following the 'required' element

Tags: javascript, html

I just have a single radio type to accept, but I can't figure out why it isn't working?

```
<div class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="radioTOS" required><p>Accept</p> 
</div>
```

Script:

```
const radio = document.querySelector(".radioTOS");

payment.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (radio.checked == null) {
        confirmBtn.style.display = 'none';
        checkout.innerHTML = 'Booked!'
    }else{
        console.log("no");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `const radio = document.querySelector("[name=radioTOS]");`

What you have is looking for an element with the class of radioTOS, but in the snippets provided there are no such classes. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector()` method returns the first Element within the `document` that matches the specified selector. If match is not found then it will return null.

As for your code -

`name` is a attribute not a `class`.

If you want to access the input type by it's `name` then `[name=radioTOS]`.

```
const radio = document.querySelector("input[name=radioTOS]");

payment.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (radio.checked === null) {
        confirmBtn.style.display = 'none';
        checkout.innerHTML = 'Booked!';
    }else{
        console.log("no");
    }
});
```